# AWK. Extract root and suffixes

Tags: unix, awk

I have a csv file, separated by semicolons. This file contains a Danish lexicon from which I need to extract the stems and suffixes.
**I need to do it in AWK!**

File:

```
adelig;adelig;adj.;1
adelig;adelige;adj.;2
adelig;adeligt;adj.;3
adelig;adeligst;adj.;5
voksen;voksen;adj.;1
voksen;voksne;adj.;2
voksen;voksent;adj.;3
voksen;voksnest;adj.;5
virkemiddel;virkemiddel;sb.;1
virkemiddel;virkemidlet;sb.;2
virkemiddel;virkemidlets;sb.;3
virkemiddel;virkemiddels;sb.;4
virkemiddel;virkemidlerne;sb.;5
virkemiddel;virkemidlernes;sb.;6
virkemiddel;virkemiddel;sb.;7
virkemiddel;virkemidler;sb.;7
virkemiddel;virkemiddels;sb.;8
virkemiddel;virkemidlers;sb.;8
```

expected output:

```
adelig;adelig; ,e,t,*,st
voksen;voks; ,ne,ent,*,nest
virkemiddel;virkemid ,let,lets,dels,lerne,lernes,del;ler,dels;lers
```

Column four are the forms. When some form is missing, the suffix is replaced by an asterisk. Like `adelig;adelig; ,e,t,*,st`
If the form (the number) is repeated, the suffixes are separated by a semicolon. Like `virkemiddel;virkemid ,let,lets,dels,lerne,lernes,del;ler,dels;lers`

I started to write this code, but I don't get the algorithm to deal with more than one possible stem. As in the case of *virkemiddel*

```
BEGIN{
FS=";"
}

{

    lemm=$1;
    form=$2;

    if(match(form, lemm) > 0)
    {
        root=lemm;
        sub(root,"",form);
        suf[$1]=suf[$1]","form;
    }
    else
    {
        split($1,a,"");
        split($2,b,"");


        s="";
        for(i in a)
        { 
            if(b[i]!=a[i])
            {
                break;
            }
            s = s "" a[i];
        }
    }
    root=s;

}
```

Comment: looking for the stem may be way easier to do with Python ([os.path.commonprefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix)). I don't think awk is indicated for this.

Comment: It is not clear why the last row in the expected output has `;lers` instead of `,lers`.

Comment: @fedorqui El motivo, es que necesito agrupar los sufijos cuando el numero de la forma se repite. Como la forma 7 y 8 del ejemplo.

Comment: It is not clear: please give a detailed explanation instead of just relying on the output.

Comment: The `dels;lers` is perfectly clear. What is not clear is why `voks;` has a semicolon, but `virkemid` doesn't.

Comment: It's a typo, virkemind also has semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some awk code to find the common prefix length and determine the list of suffixes. I have not handled the missing form, nor the repeated number, but it should give you a start

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }
{ words[$1] = words[$1] FS $2 }
END {
    for (word in words) {
        sub("^"FS, "", words[word])
        num_words = split(words[word], these_words)
        prefix_length = common_prefix_length(these_words, num_words)

        suffixes = ""
        sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<=num_words; i++) {
            suffixes = suffixes sep substr(these_words[i],prefix_length+1)
            sep = ","
        }
        print word, substr(these_words[1], 1, prefix_length), suffixes
    }
}

function common_prefix_length(w, n                 ,i,j,minlen, char) {
    minlen = length(w[1])
    for (i=2; i<=n; i++) 
        if (length(w[i]) < minlen)
            minlen = length(w[i])

    for (i=1; i <= minlen; i++) {
        char = substr(w[1], i, 1)
        for (j=2; j <= n; j++)
            if (substr(w[j], i, 1) != char)
                return i-1
    }
    return minlen
}
```

The output, given your input, is

```
voksen;voks;en,ne,ent,nest
virkemiddel;virkemid;del,let,lets,dels,lerne,lernes,del,ler,dels,lers
adelig;adelig;,e,t,st
```

Comment: I have been studying the algorithm and how to add the two details that Glenn Jackman hasn't completed. But I can't fit them !. Any ideas??

Comment: @fedorqui, it's idiomatic awk to separate actual function parameters from function local variables with a sequence of whitespace: "Usually when you write a function, you know how many names you intend to use for arguments and how many you intend to use as local variables. It is conventional to place some extra space between the arguments and the local variables, in order to document how your function is supposed to be used." [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Definition-Syntax.html#Definition-Syntax)

Comment: @glennjackman oh, sorry about that, I wasn't aware of it. I struggle to see the benefit of it, though. What's the need to give `minlen` for example, if it is set later on in the function?

Comment: The only way to declare a variable as local to a function is to add it to the parameter list. If it does not receive a value when called, the variable is simply zero or empty, just like a regular awk variable.

Comment: Finally! thanks to glenn jackman code, I resolved most of my problem. The only thing left for me to solve is a problem with the encoding. I think it's the encoding, but not sure. I'll edit my question to show it to you.

Comment: You should add an answer of your own, showing your work. Feel free to make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a good starting point in Python. It used [`os.path.commonprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) to get the stem from a list of words.

```
import os
import csv

file="a"
prev_word=""
words=[]
data=dict()
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(
    open(file),
    delimiter=";",
    fieldnames=['common','word','type','num']
    )

for row in csv_reader:
    word = row['common']
    if not prev_word or word == prev_word:
        words.append(row['word'])
    else:
        common=os.path.commonprefix(words)
        data[prev_word] = words
        words=[]
    prev_word = word

data[prev_word] = words
for word,values in data.iteritems():
    common = os.path.commonprefix(values)
    suffixes = [i[len(common):] for i in values]
    suffixes = [i if len(i) else '*' for i in suffixes]
    print "%s;%s;%s" %(word,common,','.join(suffixes))
```

It returns:

```
voksen;voks;ne,ent,nest
virkemiddel;virkemid;let,lets,dels,lerne,lernes,del,ler,dels,lers
adelig;adelig;*,e,t,st
```

Comment: Your code is great!!. But, I need to do this in AWK.

Comment: Then good luck with implementing the `os.path.commonprefix` in awk! It is not trivial. I don't see why this should be done in `awk` since it hits its limits.

Answer (score 2):

Three solutions in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr). First, one which uses the extraction language to construct an explicit data model based on structures, then processes the structures:

```
@(do
   (defstruct inflection ()
     word type index)

   (defstruct dict-entry ()
     root variants max-index))
@(collect :vars (dict))
@  (all)
@word;@(skip)
@  (and)
@    (collect :gap 0 :vars (infl))
@word;@variant;@type;@index
@      (bind infl @(new inflection word variant type type index (toint index)))
@    (end)
@    (bind dict @(new dict-entry root word variants infl
                      max-index [find-max-key infl > .index]))
@  (end)
@(end)
@(do (each ((d dict))
       (let* ((vs (mapcar .word d.variants))
              (prefix (reduce-left (ret [@1 0..(mismatch @1 @2)]) vs))
              (plen (len prefix))
              (prefix [(first vs) 0..plen]))
         (put-string `@{d.root};@prefix; `)
         (each ((i (range 2 d.max-index)))
           (let ((vlist [keepql i d.variants .index]))
             (put-char #\,)
             (put-string
               (if (null vlist)
                 "*"
                 [cat-str (mapcar (ret [@1.word plen..:]) vlist) ";"]))))
         (put-line))))
```

Run:

```
$ txr stems.txr data
adelig;adelig; ,e,t,*,st
voksen;voks; ,ne,ent,*,nest
virkemiddel;virkemid; ,let,lets,dels,lerne,lernes,del;ler,dels;lers
```

Note the slight discrepancy:

```
virkemiddel;virkemid; ,let,lets,dels,lerne,lernes,del;ler,dels;lers
                    ^
```

This semicolon is excluded in the original desired output; no rationale is given for the basis of the exclusion, so for now it is treated as a typographical error.

The expression `(ret [@1 0..(mismatch @1 @2)])` produces a two-argument function which returns the common prefix of a pair of strings. To return the common prefix of a list of strings, we use this unction as the kernel in a `reduce-left`.

Second version, without data structuring. Produces identical output on `data`:

```
@(repeat)
@  (all)
@word;@(skip)
@  (and)
@    (collect :gap 0)
@word;@variant;@type;@strindex
@      (bind index @(toint strindex))
@    (end)
@    (do
       (let* ((prefix (reduce-left (ret [@1 0..(mismatch @1 @2)]) variant))
              (plen (len prefix))
              (max-index [find-max index])
              (v-i-pairs (zip variant index)))
        (put-string `@word;@prefix; `)
        (each ((i (range 2 max-index)))
          (let ((vlist [keepql i v-i-pairs second]))
            (put-char #\,)
            (put-string
              (cat-str (or (mapcar (aret [@1 plen..:]) vlist)
                           '("*"))
                       ";"))))
        (put-line)))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Pure TXR Lisp solution, not using the extraction language. One giant expression which reads the input lines, splits them, converts the fourth field to integer, groups the entries by their root word and so forth:

```
(flow
  (get-lines)
  (keep-matches (`@a;@b;@c;@d` @1)
    (list a b c (toint d)))
  (partition-by first)
  (mapcar transpose)
  (mapdo (tb ((word variant type index))
           (let* ((prefix (reduce-left (ret [@1 0..(mismatch @1 @2)]) variant))
                  (plen (len prefix))
                  (max-index [find-max index])
                  (v-i-pairs (zip variant index)))
             (put-string `@(first word);@prefix; `)
             (each ((i (range 2 max-index)))
               (let ((vlist [keepql i v-i-pairs second]))
                 (put-char #\,)
                 (put-string
                   (cat-str (or (mapcar (aret [@1 plen..:]) vlist)
                                '("*"))
                            ";"))))
             (put-line)))))
```

Run:

```
$ txr stems3.tl < data
adelig;adelig; ,e,t,*,st
voksen;voks; ,ne,ent,*,nest
virkemiddel;virkemid; ,let,lets,dels,lerne,lernes,del;ler,dels;lers
```

Comment: @felipsmartins TXR doesn't just smell of Lisp; it contains a Lisp dialect called TXR Lisp which is embedded in the pattern-based extraction language or used stand-alone. This Lisp dialect is geared toward succinct, fluid data munging, addressing many of the nagging "ergonomic" issues in mainstream Lisp dialects.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which I have obtained the expected result.
The notes in the code indicate the main changes to the glenn code.

```
BEGIN {
FS=OFS=";"
}

{ 
    words[$1";"$3] = words[$1";"$3] FS $2;
    num[$1";"$3]=num[$1";"$3] $4 FS; #Array to store numbers in the fourth column by two ID's
}

END {
    for (item in words) {
        sub("^"FS, "", words[item]);
        words_n = split(words[item], extrac);
        split(num[item],numbers); #Extract numbers one by one, in order to compare them.
        split(item,cab,";");
        long = extract_stem(extrac, words_n);

        suffix = "";
        sep = ",";

        for (i=1; i<=words_n; i++)
        {
            suf=substr(extrac[i],long+1)
            if(suf!="") #Avoid null values from suffixes.
            {
                suffix = suffix sep suf;
            }

            if(numbers[i]==numbers[i+1]) #Compare numbers with the next number
            {
                sep=";";
            }
            else if((numbers[i+1]-numbers[i])!= 1) #Subtract numbers to its previous number
            {
                sep=",*,";
            }
            else
            {
                sep=",";
            }
        }
        print cab[1], substr(extrac[1], 1, long), " "suffix
    }
}


function extract_stem(wrd, nmr ,i,j,min, chr) { #This is the magic of glenn jackman!
    min = length(wrd[1])
    for (i=2; i<=nmr; i++)
    {
        if (length(wrd[i]) < min)
        {
            min = length(wrd[i]);
        }
    }

    for (i=1; i <= min; i++)
    {
        chr = substr(wrd[1], i, 1)
        for (j=2; j <= nmr; j++)
        {
            if (substr(wrd[j], i, 1) != chr)
            {
                return i-1;
            }
        }
    }
    return min
}
```

I had to modify the code. I had not considered this casuistry.
When lemma is the same for the verb and the adverb.

```
abe;abe;sb.;1
abe;aben;sb.;2
abe;abens;sb.;3
abe;abes;sb.;4
abe;aberne;sb.;5
abe;abernes;sb.;6
abe;aber;sb.;7
abe;abers;sb.;8
abe;abe;vb.;1
abe;ab;vb.;2
abe;abet;vb.;3
abe;aber;vb.;4
abe;abede;vb.;6
abe;abes;vb.;7
abe;abedes;vb.;8
```